# Get changed line numbers on GitHub commits

Tags: git, github, git-diff

When you go to a repo on GitHub and click on one of the commits, apart from the commit message, the website also shows you the changed source files with blue areas (+) for additions an red (-) for deletions. Now I want to be able to get the same thing programmatically. That is, I have cloned the repo to my computer and I want to go to the cloned dir and do a git diff commit# or something so that the output would be the changed source files AND the changed line numbers. I have spent quite some time looking for solutions online and there are none workable for me! Any suggestions please?

NB: There are git diff --stat or --numstat, etc. but they only give you the changed files and the number of changes. What I want are the specific line numbers. It seems that git diff doesn't have any options for outputting that.

Comment: Are you talking about the lines that start with `@@`?  Those are just in the output of `git diff` along with the actual changes.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. So how do I read this thing for a changed file: @@ -217,7 +217,8 @@? I read some explanation but still unclear. Does "-" denote from line, # lines before commit and "+" denote from line, # lines after commit?

Comment: This explanation should clear things up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?